# Multivariational regression

Tags: regression, mathematical-modeling, least-squares

I have been given following model

$\ln(y)=\beta_0+\beta_1a+\beta_2a^2+\beta_3a^3+\beta_4a^4+\beta_5b$

and a set of observations that describe relation between $y$ and $\{a, b\}$. The goal is to estimate $\beta$-coefficients such that the model best explains the observations. How can I estimate them?

Also, why would one want to put the logarithm on $y$?

I have tried least squares (with $\ln(y)$), but the model tends to overestimate $y$. This might be due to outliers (which are present in the observational data), or maybe least squares is not a fit for this in a first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the model $$z=\ln(y)=\beta_0+\beta_1a+\beta_2a^2+\beta_3a^3+\beta_4a^4+\beta_5b$$ all the $\beta$'s will be obtained using multilinear regression just as you apparently did.

The problem is that this is just a first step since what is measured is $y$ and not $\log(y)$. In such a case, you need to start a nonlinear regression of the same data for the model $$y=\exp(\beta_0+\beta_1a+\beta_2a^2+\beta_3a^3+\beta_4a^4+\beta_5b)$$ for which you have good starting values from the first step.

**Edit**

If you do not want (or cannot) use nonlinear regression, you can stay with weighted  multilinear regression. This is a good compromise (see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFittingExponential.html)).

Comment: You're saying it's a first step. What are key differences of the coefficients $\beta_i$ which you'd get from least squares estimation for $z = \dots$ compared to the $\beta_i$ which you'd get from some MLE for $y = \exp(\dots)$?

Comment: @Roland. They could be quite different if you try to minimize the sum of squared errors. In fact, if errors are small, the linearized step corresponds more or less (easy to prove) to the minimization of the sum of squares of relative errors in the second step. The advantage of running the first step is that the parameters are reasonable and consistent (but they can be quite different from the ones obtained in the nonlinear regression).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will try to use matlab's nlinfit() with the $\beta$'s obtained previously.

Comment: @student. This is the way to go ! Cheers.

Comment: I've tried, but the model tends to return huge numbers - it eventually overflows and returns $\infty$. Is there a way around this? I cannot change the model, neither the data - both is given. I've tried rescaling both inputs and output by $10^-6$, but I get rank deficiency warnings.

Comment: Could you send me the data (my e-mail address is in my profile) ? I shall look at the problem which is not normal if you initialized the $\beta$'s using the values from the first step. Try also what Wolfram suggests (not rigorous but almost OK).